# Creating particle system emitting nurbs sphere

Tags: python, particles, nurbs-surface

I'm new to blender, and using it for science visualisation.

I'm working with a large number of points and would like to use nurbs sphere as particles to make everything run more smoothly. However when I set my nurbs sphere as an instance object, everything disappears and I don't know why.
It works well with a sphere.

Thanks !

Comment: I would highly recommend not using nurbs. either use icospheres, but if you can re-recreate your effect in Geometry (I'm guessing you're not talking about simulated particles) and don't mind using Cycles, you should use points. They are perfectly spherical and super cheap to render

Comment: NURBS Sphere works fine it is converted to mesh. Please check your Geometry Nodes set up for errors or share a screenshot of it.